# Cannot Return Result from jQuery AJAX from a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function using jQuery AJAX to return data from a data file. However, I cannot get the function to return the value. Any ideas?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function getdata() {
            var result = 'default value';

            $.ajax({
                url: 'data/json/load.json',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    result = response.data;
                    console.log('this is working and the result is: ' + result);
                    return result;
                }
            });

            return result;
        }

        var returndata = getdata();

        //I'm trying to return the results from my AJAX call here:
        console.log(returndata)
    });
```

Comment: ajax requests work in async manner you have to use callback function so when your data is ready it will run your call back function

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    async function getdata() {
        await $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.publicapis.org/entries',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                result = response;
            }
        });
        return result
    }

    getdata().then((result) => console.log(result));
    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `returndata` will always be `undefined` here.  At least in OPs they had a return from getdata() - this does not.

Answer (score 0):

You should get familiar with how [Promises](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp) work, they're very convenient.

That's how You could use them in your code:

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
async function getdata() {
    var result = 'default value'


    await $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.publicapis.org/entries',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            result = response
            console.log('this is working and the result is: ' + result)
        }
    })

    return result;
}

getdata().then(function(result) {
    returndata = result
    console.log(returndata)
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```